# Power Series Expansion

Tags: power-series

How can I find the Maclaurin series for $f(x)=e^x$/$(1-x^2)$? I have tried expanding it out but I am having trouble with the algebra of it.

Answer (score 1):

One may recall that, as $x \to 0$,
$$
\begin{align}
e^x&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}, \quad x \in \mathbb{C}, \tag1\\\\
\frac{1}{1-x^2}&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{2n}=\frac1{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(1+(-1)^n)x^{n}, \quad |x|<1, \tag2
\end{align}
$$ then using the Cauchy product we get

> $$
> \frac{e^x}{1-x^2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(1+(-1)^{n-k})}{2k!}\right)x^{n}, \quad |x|<1. \tag3
> $$

The series on the right hand side of $(3)$ starts as
$$
\frac{e^x}{1-x^2}=1+x+\frac3{2}x^2+\frac7{6}x^3+\cdots
$$

Comment: A small nitpick: (1) and (2) are not only when $x\to 0$ (the first holds for all $x\in\mathbb{C}$, the second when $\lvert x\rvert \leq 1$).

Comment: @ClementC. It is not true that the second holds when $|x|\leq1$ :)

Comment: Sorry. $\lvert x\rvert < 1$, of course... nitpicking away!